# A question on multivariate integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a given function. Suppose $\boldsymbol{f}:\mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is the vector version of $f$, e.g., $\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{t})=[f(t_1),f(t_2),\cdot\cdot\cdot,f(t_N)]^{\top}$, for $t=[t_1,t_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,t_N]^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^N$, from $\boldsymbol{0}$ to $\boldsymbol{x}$, where $\boldsymbol{x}=[x_1,x_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_N]^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ is a fixed column vector.

The question is when the integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathcal{C}} \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{t}) \cdot d\boldsymbol{t}
\end{equation}
is equal to
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^N \int_0^{x_i} f(t) dt.
\end{equation}

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are always identical due to your definition for $\mathbf{f}$. Consider parametrizing your curve $\mathcal{C}$ as $\mathbf t(s)$ for $s\in[0,1]$ then the first integral becomes

$$\int_0^1 \mathbf f(\mathbf t(s)) \cdot \left.\frac{d\mathbf{t}}{ds}\right|_s ds$$

where $d\mathbf t/ds$ is the tangent vector to the curve. This gives

$$\int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf f(\mathbf t(s))_i \left(\left.\frac{d\mathbf{t}}{ds}\right|_s\right)_i ds$$

Because $\mathbf f(\mathbf t) =  [f(t_1),\ldots f(t_n)]^T$ the $i$-th component of $\mathbf f(\mathbf t(s))$ is just $f(t_i(s))$ and similarly the $i$-th component of the tangent is just the gradient $t_i$ wrt $s$. This means that the integral becomes

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^1 f(t_i(s))\, \left.\frac{dt_i}{ds}\right|_s ds$$

which we can see is equal to

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^{x_i}f(t) dt$$

In general this does not hold because we cannot "pull the  index inside" the argument of $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf t)$ for an arbitrary vector field. You might be interested to read about [conservative fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field), which are vector fields where the path integral is the same whatever path you take between two points.

**Scalar potential:**

A vector field is conservative if there is a scalar field $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf t) = \nabla \phi(\mathbf t)$. This implies that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t_i}(x_i)=f(x_i) \Rightarrow \nabla\phi(\mathbf x)=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf x)$. We can see that for a scalar field the value at a point $\mathbf x$ is given by

$$\phi(\mathbf x) = \int_0^\mathbf{x} \nabla \phi (\mathbf t) \cdot d\mathbf{t}$$
or using the equality above
$$\phi(\mathbf x) = \int_0^\mathbf{x} \mathbf f (\mathbf t) \cdot d\mathbf{t}$$
which is exactly the integral we were interested in. Thereby confirming our intuition. Here is a picture of this idea where $f(t)=\sin(t)$ in two dimenions, so $\phi(x,y)=-\cos(x)-\cos(y)$

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, it helps a lot!

Comment: @Richie, you're welcome. I added an extra explanation about conservative fields which helps show why this form for $\mathbf{f}$ leads to the same integral for different paths because I found it interesting.